# airplay command not found

Tags: linux, bash, aircrack-ng, airplay

I am trying to run `airplay`, and the response is command not found. 
Specifically:

```
# airplay-ng 
-bash: airplay-ng: command not found
```

What can I do to fix it?

I tried to run it under `sudo` and I got the same error. 
I tried to uninstall air crack and install again, and it didn't work.

The other commands run perfect, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The aircrack-ng package doesn't have an `airplay-ng` command - I assume you intended to use `aireplay-ng`.

Comment: how can i get airplay-ng

Comment: Like I said, that command does not exist. You are probably thinking of `aireplay-ng` (note the different spelling).